# how to copy lines at a particular intervals in vim editor

Tags: vim

I need to copy lines 10,20,30,40 etc to another file in vim editor. how to yank lines at specific intervals in vim.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to step over lines AFAICT, but you can use a macro to append to a register:

1. Clear some register (say, `a`) and go to the starting line (say, line 10):

   ```
   :let @a = '' | 10<cr>
   ```

   (`<cr>` indicating <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Start a macro (say in the `b` register) - `qb`, append the current line to the first register - `"Ayy`, move *n* (say 10) lines down - `10j`, call for executing the macro recursively - `@b` and save it - `q`:

   ```
   qb"Ayy10j@bq
   ```
3. Then execute the macro:

   ```
   @b
   ```

You can then switch to another buffer and paste the contents of register `a` with `"ap`.